# What determines whether 'Warranty' appears in About This Mac?

Tags: macos, mac

At the foot of the **About This Mac** window:

- some Macs show *License Agreement*
- some Macs show *License and Warranty*.

What determines whether the word *Warranty* appears?

(For someone whose late 2013 Mac Pro 6,1 serial number is listed in their [support profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com/), the word does **not** appear.)

Answer (score 1):

Are the two spellings of 'license' and 'licence' accurate in your question? The second spelling is usually a British spelling variation, (like labour for labor, aluminium for aluminum, &c.)

I would hazard a guess that the word 'Warrantee' appears because different legal conditions are in effect if this particular Mac/OS X was purchased in the UK.

My iMac, registered with AppleCare and purchased in the the US, does not have 'Warrantee.'

Comment: The screenshots that I have seen show *License and Warranty* – thanks for the question. I have edited the opening post.